# Ground detection circuit

Tags: circuit-design, ground, pullup, logic-level, pulldown

I'm designing a circuit containing a button with a pull-up/pull-down logic depending on whether I'm grounding a header. The button triggers a GPIO that will detect if the header is grounded thanks to the falling/rising edge when I push the button. On my GPIO I want to be able to know whether the header is grounded and if the button is being pressed.

Here is the circuit I have designed so far :
[image]

You can try it out [here.](https://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmAzNALAdkggnMmAGxFYKSpIZEhLm0CmAtGGAFADK4BIeNYPVMigiAZgEMANgGcGI5GwBKIJkN41VwohhGQQGPelS6o0BGwBO3YQJs9kCGnrDk4bAO7WUj8MgAc3k5syJBYIGoOToH6IABGAC4AdgD6AJaJbACSKJABtihYdsJ6MEhGHjl5PPn5kGzSXpEFwk3OIPEWAK4MFciF0X1FUGwADr4BTWD%204ZA6ECVsAObjM3PTQiXDIWGa4Bg6zvsxAMbisenJsQD28fFXALbBoStqfobCOqfnKelsx5WraKoWa6WDwSB4SFQ6EwvAqdDIWFQvx4MjEUxwdjLDZeShDBZWDABPjw4Qk5zgpYvGzTbS6CpTAJqMBYGhqOqeXZgI67ckVInqLx8zz5Ek1HgcoEgwaAyUy4E6GWtXq5QH5BXDEWCEH5ZWeCI%20RnROpWA1s4QavSuNzYi0gtQ4hZAA)

As you can see, if I'm grounding my header the circuit works with a pull-down logic, if the header is in the air we have a pull-up. It works well but I have two concerns about this circuit :

The first one is that when my header is in the air I get 2.5V instead of 3.3V which might be a problem in the future. I'm looking for a solution to get a nice 3.3V.

My second concern is that is find my logic a bit heavy and I'm looking for a simpler way to solve my problem (maybe without any diode?)

Any kind of help will be very appreciated.

Comment: The schematic is very unclear. Give designators to the components, R1, R2, etc., so we can discuss them. Where is the header? What is the SPDT switch? What is the SPST switch? What is the 0 V gap about? Is the inverter something separate from the MCU? What's the real problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to make the GPIO pull-up/pull-down mode externally configurable by jumper?

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for your feedback, I updated my schematic following your advices. The 0V represents the probe, it's an output. I want to be able to detect if my header is grounded and if the button is being pressed with one GPIO only. for that, I'm trying to detect the falling/rising edges on my GPIO. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: That's a bit better, but how is the GPIO supposed to tell the difference between the header and the button? For example, you could do a power-up test to read the input and determine which way it is pulled **if** you could guarantee that the button won't be pressed.

Comment: @Transistor Exactly, when booting up, I can guarantee that the button is not pressed so I will determine the state of my header (I'm assuming as well that the state of the header will notchange). After that, I can set up my GPIO in pull-up/down mode depending on the state of the header and wait for a button pressure.

Comment: What is the "0V" component lower center?

Comment: @AnalogKid That is a volt meter component from the fallstad circuit editor. It has an infinity resistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my GPIO I want to be able to know whether the header is grounded and if the button is being pressed.

For those two variables there are four possible combinations.  In a snapshot of the GPIO input, you cannot resolve 4 states with only one digital input.  You can see a state change and evaluate it in the context of previous readings, but note that there are two possible input operations for each state change.  For example, the header grounded while the button is pressed (a low at the GPIO input) looks the same as the header open and the button at rest.

Assuming you have worked through that in your software, here is a first pass at a reduced solution.  Your static GPIO voltage is lower than desired because it comes from a voltage divider with three resistors plus a diode.  This circuit has a similar approach but had only two resistors, that are 10x apart in value.

For either header condition, U1A provides a consistent pull up/down impedance to the GPIO input in the rest state (button not pushed).

When the button is pressed and the header jumper is in, the hard GND connection overpowers R2.  When the jumper is out, R1 overpowers R2 in the other direction.  Both resistor values can be adjusted to get the right combination of network impedance and switching margin for your GPIO input stage.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the design I needed, Thanks!

Comment: Yur wekkom.  Note that the inverter does not have to be that specific part.  There is no requirement for a CD4000-series part or a Schmitt trigger stage; it is what's in my design library.

Answer (score 0):

> @Transistor Exactly, when booting up, I can guarantee that the button is not pressed so I will determine the state of my header (I'm assuming as well that the state of the header will not change).

Well then the solution is as simple as a single resistor. In your `init` routine declare a variable `invLogic = digitalRead(pin)`. That will then be true if inverted logic is in operation (pull low for "on"). Use that to correct any subsequent readings.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR6q95.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> After that, I can set up my GPIO in pull-up/down mode depending on the state of the header and wait for a button pressure.

No, you won't be using your internal pull-up or pull-down. You don't need it as you have an external one. The internal ones only exist to save having to use external components.

Comment: In my problem my header is not 3V3 or GND, it is GND or Not Connected. Furthermore, I can't change my button wiring dynamically as you are doing in your schematic. I would need one unique schematic for both cases.

Comment: I read your question as, "I want to be able to configure a GPIO to use either an NPN or PNP switching arrangement by means of a header." Now I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I see two simple options. The first one uses a XOR gate to invert the button signal depending on the header status like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5waYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second idea supports your intention to change the GPIO resistor pull direction depending on the header signal like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe4EKh.png)</sup>